# Passing arguments to methods

Tags: ruby

I have a method `gcd` that takes two arguments. When I do this:

```
gcd (20,40)
```

I get this error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

Removing the parentheses fixes the problem, but is there some way to use parentheses and still get this code to work?

Comment: Ruby already has a gcd. `12.gcd(30) #=> 6`

Comment: I know, I was trying to illustrate my problem. But, thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put space between method and arguments. It should be:

```
gcd(20, 40)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pass arguments to a method:

- in parentheses directly after the method name
- without parentheses with whitespace after the method name

You have white space after the method, ergo you are using option #2 and are passing a *single* argument `(20, 40)` to the method, but `(20, 40)` is not legal syntax.