# Beginner on Ruby making a calculator

Tags: ruby, integer, calculator

this is my first entry to StackOverflow and I'm a newbie coder.

So I'm making a simple addition calc and I added commas in the last 2 lines to print out integers ...

What am I missing?  The error says

> C:/Ruby193/rubystuff/ex1.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ',' print
>   ("The result of the addition is " +,result)

I thought this was the right thing to do ... i must have missed something simple.

```
print ("Please enter your name: ")
name = gets
puts ("Hello, " + name)
print ("Enter a number to add: ")
num1 = gets
print ("Enter a second number to add: ")
num2 = gets
result = Integer(num1) + Integer(num2)

print result


print ("The result of the addition is ",result)
print ("So the result of adding " + num1.chomp + " plus " + num2.chomp + " equals: ",result)
```

Comment: When making function calls, don't introduce a space between the method and the arguments. That can lead to parsing errors. Secondly, `print` doesn't add a newline, `puts` does. Most of these should be `puts(...)`. It's also convention to call `num1.to_i` instead of the `Integer()` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843659/passing-arguments-to-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has string interpolation and I think most would argue that's the most idiomatic way of doing things. RubyMonk does a great job explaining it [here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics)

by changing the 'print' call to the puts method you can do:

```
puts "The result of the additions is #{result}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pass arguments to a method:

- in parentheses directly after the method name
- without parentheses with whitespace after the method name

You have white space after the method, ergo you are using option #2 and are passing a *single* argument `("The result of the addition is ",result)` to the method, but `("The result of the addition is ",result)` is not legal syntax.